# How to concatenate a string to each JSON node result in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON output from an API written in python I am fetching the results in JSON but I want to append a string let say abc.com to each result.

```
  {
  "subdomains": [
    "results",
    "www",
    "sip",
    "cdn",
    "pavpn",
    "intranet",
    "laxvpn",
    "news",
    "files",
  ],
}
```

So each returned value should be parsed out and appended like `results.abc.com` `pavpn.abc.com` etc so I can get a clean string out of it containing only subdomain plus abc.com appended to that.

I have tried many solutions:

```
`result = map(lambda x: str(x) + "." + str(domain_name), response.text)`
```

I want the output to be

```
subdomain.abc.com
subdomain.abc.com
```

etc..
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
>>> d = {
  "subdomains": [
    "results",
    "www",
    "sip",
    "cdn",
    "pavpn",
    "intranet",
    "laxvpn",
    "news",
    "files",
  ],
}

>>> [x + "." + domain for x in d["subdomains"]]
# result ['results.abc.com', 'www.abc.com', 'sip.abc.com', 'cdn.abc.com', 'pavpn.abc.com', 'intranet.abc.com', 'laxvpn.abc.com', 'news.abc.com', 'files.abc.com']
```

Comment: yes great! But on the top of that i want plain text output like
subdomain.abc.com\n(newline) subdomain.abc.com

Comment: Use simple [Python .join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) 
Which will be: `"\n".join([x + "." + domain for x in d["subdomains"]])`